# MySQL insert ignore for duplicates but fail on foreign key errors

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

Is there a way in a single MySQL statement to insert records into a table, ignoring duplicate key errors, but failing if a foreign key constraint fails?

```
insert ignore into `table` ...
```

will ignore both duplicate and foreign key errors, so that will not work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE
```

will ignore all errors, it's a global ignore.

You could use the following statement to ignore duplicated keys but not others

```
INSERT INTO sample (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val1','val2','val3') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=col1;
```

Comment: Also, read about REPLACE - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html

"REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted"

Comment: REPLACE might not work if the table being inserted into has foreign keys referencing it because of delete/reinsert